# Map Either of Two Source Fields to a Single Target Field

Tags: etl, aws-glue

I'm very new to AWS Glue, and I'm struggling to get around an issue. We recently changed one of the field names in our database, and now I can't figure out how to create the mapping in Glue to support both the legacy and new field names.

The legacy mapping looked something like:

```
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [...("json_property.Foo Bar", "string", "foo_bar", "string")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")
```

We normalized the json property names, and `json_property['Foo Bar']` became `json_property.foo_bar`. I tried doing this:

```
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [...("json_property.Foo Bar", "string", "foo_bar", "string"), ("json_property.foo_bar", "string", "foo_bar", "string")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")
```

Essentially I tried mapping both source fields to the same target field. As expected, this caused an error when attempting to run the job...

Is there any way I can have the process take `json_property.foo_bar` OR `json_property['Foo Bar']` (whichever exists) from the source and map to the `foo_bar` target field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out by adding a map step prior to using `ApplyMapping` in order to map the legacy field name to the updated field name

```
## @type: DataSource
## @args: [database = "s3 olap", table_name = "example", transformation_ctx = "datasource0"]
## @return: datasource0
## @inputs: []
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "s3 olap, table_name = "example", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")

## @type: Map
## @args: [f = MergeLegacyFields, transformation_ctx = "merge_legacy_fields"]
## @return: datasource_mapped
## @inputs: [frame = datasource0]
def MergeLegacyFields(rec):
  if 'Foo Bar' in rec:
    rec['foo_bar'] = rec['Foo Bar']
  return rec

datasource_mapped = Map.apply(frame = datasource0, f = MergeLegacyFields, transformation_ctx = "merge_legacy_fields")

## @type: ApplyMapping
## @args: [mapping = [("foo_bar", "string", "foo_bar", "timestamp")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1"]
## @return: applymapping1
## @inputs: [frame = datasource_mapped]
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource_mapped, mappings = [("foo_bar", "string", "foo_bar", "string")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")
```